# ASP.NET Web site in Azure without converting it in to ASP.NET Web application

Tags: asp.net, azure

Is it possible to deploy ASP.NET Web site in Azure without converting it in to ASP.NET Web application? Is it possible then please provide some tutorial link ?I search but didn't found any link.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy an ASP.NET Web Site to Windows Azure Web Sites without having to convert it to a Web Application. Simply right click the **ASP.NET Web Site**, choose **Publish Web Site**, choose FTP and enter the FTP credentials of your Windows Azure Web Site:

[image]

Make sure you change the directory to **site/wwwroot** or you'll break the Windows Azure Web Site.